# migrating to latest jquery validate plugin

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I'm currently using the jquery validate plugin version 1.9.0 the latest is version 1.11.0. When i migrated to the latest version, the error checking on forms don't work. After reading the documentation and looking at the [examples on the site](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/), i still can't figure out a work around. (some of the examples don't work properly)

In my code i use the meta validate class to specify if a field is valid and would like to keep it in the html instead of specifying it in the JS.

```
 $("#report-listing-form").validate({
     meta: "validate",
     rules: {
         recaptcha_response_field: {
             required: true
         }
     },
     errorContainer: {},
     invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
         var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
         if (errors) {
             var message = (errors == 1)
                                    ? '1 invalid field.'
                                    : errors + ' invalid fields.';

             $("#err_report-listing-form").html(message).addClass("text-error");
         }
     },
     submitHandler: function (form) {
         alert('works');
     }
 });
```

Sample of my code is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/deArQ/42/

For the metadata to work using the older plugin had to use this plugin

```
    /* ##################################################################################################### */
/* ##################################################################################################### */
/*
 * Metadata - jQuery plugin for parsing metadata from elements
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2006 John Resig, Yehuda Katz, JÔøΩ√∂rn Zaefferer, Paul McLanahan
 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 *
 * Revision: $Id: jquery.metadata.js 4187 2007-12-16 17:15:27Z joern.zaefferer $
 *
 */

/**
 * Sets the type of metadata to use. Metadata is encoded in JSON, and each property
 * in the JSON will become a property of the element itself.
 *
 * There are three supported types of metadata storage:
 *
 *   attr:  Inside an attribute. The name parameter indicates *which* attribute.
 *          
 *   class: Inside the class attribute, wrapped in curly braces: { }
 *   
 *   elem:  Inside a child element (e.g. a script tag). The
 *          name parameter indicates *which* element.
 *          
 * The metadata for an element is loaded the first time the element is accessed via jQuery.
 *
 * As a result, you can define the metadata type, use $(expr) to load the metadata into the elements
 * matched by expr, then redefine the metadata type and run another $(expr) for other elements.
 * 
 * @name $.metadata.setType
 *
 * @example <p id="one" class="some_class {item_id: 1, item_label: 'Label'}">This is a p</p>
 * @before $.metadata.setType("class")
 * @after $("#one").metadata().item_id == 1; $("#one").metadata().item_label == "Label"
 * @desc Reads metadata from the class attribute
 * 
 * @example <p id="one" class="some_class" data="{item_id: 1, item_label: 'Label'}">This is a p</p>
 * @before $.metadata.setType("attr", "data")
 * @after $("#one").metadata().item_id == 1; $("#one").metadata().item_label == "Label"
 * @desc Reads metadata from a "data" attribute
 * 
 * @example <p id="one" class="some_class"><script>{item_id: 1, item_label: 'Label'}</script>This is a p</p>
 * @before $.metadata.setType("elem", "script")
 * @after $("#one").metadata().item_id == 1; $("#one").metadata().item_label == "Label"
 * @desc Reads metadata from a nested script element
 * 
 * @param String type The encoding type
 * @param String name The name of the attribute to be used to get metadata (optional)
 * @cat Plugins/Metadata
 * @descr Sets the type of encoding to be used when loading metadata for the first time
 * @type undefined
 * @see metadata()
 */

(function($) {

$.extend({
    metadata : {
        defaults : {
            type: 'class',
            name: 'metadata',
            cre: /({.*})/,
            single: 'metadata'
        },
        setType: function( type, name ){
            this.defaults.type = type;
            this.defaults.name = name;
        },
        get: function( elem, opts ){
            var settings = $.extend({},this.defaults,opts);
            // check for empty string in single property
            if ( !settings.single.length ) settings.single = 'metadata';

            var data = $.data(elem, settings.single);
            // returned cached data if it already exists
            if ( data ) return data;

            data = "{}";

            if ( settings.type == "class" ) {
                var m = settings.cre.exec( elem.className );
                if ( m )
                    data = m[1];
            } else if ( settings.type == "elem" ) {
                if( !elem.getElementsByTagName )
                    return undefined;
                var e = elem.getElementsByTagName(settings.name);
                if ( e.length )
                    data = $.trim(e[0].innerHTML);
            } else if ( elem.getAttribute != undefined ) {
                var attr = elem.getAttribute( settings.name );
                if ( attr )
                    data = attr;
            }

            if ( data.indexOf( '{' ) <0 )
            data = "{" + data + "}";

            data = eval("(" + data + ")");

            $.data( elem, settings.single, data );
            return data;
        }
    }
});

/**
 * Returns the metadata object for the first member of the jQuery object.
 *
 * @name metadata
 * @descr Returns element's metadata object
 * @param Object opts An object contianing settings to override the defaults
 * @type jQuery
 * @cat Plugins/Metadata
 */
$.fn.metadata = function( opts ){
    return $.metadata.get( this[0], opts );
};

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)**  Pull out all of your inline rules.  They apparently will not work like this...

```
class="{validate:{required:true, email: true}}"
```

Specify them all within `.validate({...})` instead.  Don't forget to put any names [containing special characters within quotes](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Fields_with_complex_names_.28brackets.2C_dots.29).

```
rules: {
    'listing-report-email': {
        required: true,
        email: true
    }, 
    // your other rules
},
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/4VP9X/4/** *(running jQuery 1.9.1 and JQuery Validate 1.11.0)*

---

**2)**  The `maxWords` rule requires the inclusion of the [`additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/additional-methods.js).

---

**3)**  Don't forget to wrap your code within a DOM ready event handler function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#report-listing-form").validate({
        // your rules & options
    });

});
```

---

**4)**  I also have no idea what the `meta: "validate"` option is supposed to do for you.  [It's not documented anyplace that I can find](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation), and your code seems to [work the same without it](http://jsfiddle.net/4VP9X/5/).

---

**5)**  `errorContainer: {},`

You've left your `errorContainer:` option empty.  If that's intentional, you can simply leave out this option entirely.  As per comments, replace it with the following `errorPlacement` callback function to suppress the error messages.  Then style your `.valid` and `.error` CSS classes to highlight the valid and invalid fields accordingly.

http://jsfiddle.net/4VP9X/8/

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    return false;  // will suppress all validation messages
},
```

Comment: thanks @Sparky the metadata worked in older version but had to use the plugin above (updated the question) also i left "errorContainer" empty because i don't want to show the "This field is required." error message. i just want to highlight the error fields and show the "3 invalid fields." message. any idea?

Comment: also, is there a way NOT to edit all my JS? and keep the inline rules in the html by any chance?

Comment: @user2035819, there's no way around it if you want to upgrade the plugin version.  The format for inline rules has changed.  `class="required email"`, etc. and you can no longer specify non-boolean rules like `minlength` inside of `class`.  So you'll have to fix your HTML no matter what.

Comment: ah ok, got it. last question, is there a way to only show the "3 invalid fields." and just highlight the error fields, without showing the error message "This field is required." (referring to this example http://jsfiddle.net/4VP9X/5/)

Comment: @user2035819, just style the `.valid` and `.error` CSS classes accordingly.  Then replace your `errorContainer` with the `errorPlacement` callback function.  http://jsfiddle.net/4VP9X/8/